# bootstrap 3 responsive nav bar not collapsing on mobile browser, but works with desktop browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-2012, twitter-bootstrap-3

The website I've built looks fine on a desktop browser, but on a mobile device, the navbar doesn't optimize for mobile. The inline list of pages stays put as if its on a larger screen AND the nav toggle appears to the right of the brand. Not sure what the issue is, but here is my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Home.aspx">
                        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="logo" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="../Home.aspx">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Products & Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Workflow</a></li>
                                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Sys</a></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">App</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Overview</a></li>
                                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Pricing</a></li>
                                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Demo</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

I'd appreciate it if someone could shine a light for me.

Comment: What mobile OS & browser are you seeing the problem with?

Comment: Without seeing your other code this is near impossible to trouble shoot. Can you post your code to JSFiddle or online somewhere?

Comment: @cvrebert - I'm on Windows Phone OS and IE 10, but I've been told the same problem exists on the current iPhone as well.